Debian 12 Calamares installer; directory not found error; cannot create /var/lib/urandom/random-seed
A very strange and frustrating problem. I've a live Debian 12 USB for which the Calamares installer (and also the Debian installer) fail. Calamares is more verbose in it's explanation and spits out an installation failed, directory not found error with the following detail:

Could not create new random file <pre>/var/lib/urandom/random-seed</pre>.

I tried creating /var/lib/urandom in the live system but that didn't work. It's really, really weird because I've used this exact live USB to install on this exact machine multiple times in the past. I also burned a new live USB using a fresh image from the Debian website and had the exact same problem. I'm baffled.


It seems that the issue was the result of silicon oil leaking from a thermal pad on top of the target SSD; the oil had been tracking along the length of the drive and finally reached the pads.
I cleaned it up with some 100% IPA, popped it back in the machine and Debian installed as it should first time.
